# IIS6 - Why won't my Custom error page display?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-6, fiddler

I have a custom error page that should display for HTTP 404 errors.  It does not and I am having difficulty figuring out why.

My web.config is set

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Fiddler shows a 401.2, followed by a 404 for a single POST.  Both errors should be custom.  The 401.2 is working because I see it in fiddler.  The 404 happens immediately after so all I see in the browser is the generic 404 error.  I should see my custom 404 page.

Why won't my custom HTTP 404 page showup?

Comment: What's 404.2? Never heard of it, or any 404.x of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the URL you are testing with? If it's not a file type handled by ASP.NET (e.g. /foo/bar.txt) then you won't see the ASP.NET defined 404 handler.

-Oisin

Comment: The Custom page is set to type "URL" and the page is "/NotFound.html".  I will try replacing it with an aspx page.

Comment: i don't think you're following me. you can assign a custom 404 handler in web.config, and you can assign one in IIS. The web.config handler only gets invoked if someone tries to access an asp.net page that does not exist (/foo.aspx) - the IIS handler gets called for all else.

Comment: I think I follow you now.  I am going to http://mysite/foo.html.  I do not have any special handlers setup in the web.config.  They are only set it IIS as described in my first comment.  I am also seeing "The specific request cannot be executed from current application pool."  Some small tinker I made must have exploited this.  Tried registry fix on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2006/09/01/735684.aspx .  Didnt work.

Comment: Ok, this pretty much fixed the problem.  Last thing I had to do was disable the "Show friendly errors" option in IE.  Thanks @x0n

Comment: You can avoid the IE Friendly Error page limit by returning more than 512 characters in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for what the `404.x` codes mean here's this

[HTTP 404.x-File or Directory Not Found](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758476%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

- None - File or directory not found.
- 1 - Web site not accessible on the requested port.
- 2 - Web service extension lockdown policy prevents this request.
- 3 - MIME map policy prevents this request.

Seems to be an IIS specific code, not sure if IIS sends these details with the response

Comment: No, maybe my question is not clear enough.  I will update it.

Comment: IIS provides the "substatus" only in the response body; it wouldn't be legal (under the standard) to actually change the response code in the response status line.