# IIS 6 : CustomError Redirecting Values to avoid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis

I'm trying to catch different HttpError to check what is causing trouble in my .Net application.

Actually, here is the what my customError contains on my application :

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.htm">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/ErrorPage400.htm" />
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/ErrorPage401.htm" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPage403.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPage404.htm" />
    <error statusCode="408" redirect="~/ErrorPage408.htm" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPage500.htm" />
    <error statusCode="503" redirect="~/ErrorPage503.htm" />
  </customErrors>
```

The thing is that I got redirected on this page : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318380/fr

Is it some kind of default redirection?

This is causing trouble to my application because this page is embedded in an "uncloseable" Window. On my error pages, I got a button that allows the user to close the page but since I'm not redirected on one of my pages, can't click on it.

If I check the page,I can see there is no 408 Error Code for IIS 5 or 6. Is it why it's causing trouble? This is my guess but I'd like to know if someone knows  the exact reason

Comment: 503 either. "Is it why it's causing trouble?" i don't think, i suppose it ignoring by IIS.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748304/iis6-why-wont-my-custom-error-page-display